# InnerHTML not displaying the content in string

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I am trying to display two buttons with .innerHTML but it doesn't display the content put in the string.
The console is not showing any error and I've checked for typos but I haven't found anything.

Here's my HTML :

```
<div class="buttons">
   <div class="buttons_inner" id="buttonShiny"></div>
</div>
```

And here's my JS :

```
const shiny = document.getElementById('buttonShiny');

const displayButtonShiny = (pokemon) => {
  const shinyHTMLString = `
    <button class="buttons_shiny" onclick="document.getElementById('pokemonSprite').src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/${pokemon.id}.png'">Shiny</button>
    <button class="buttons_normal" onclick="document.getElementById('pokemonSprite').src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png'">Normal</button>
    `;
    shiny.innerHTML = shinyHTMLString;
};
```

The content in the shinyHTMLString should be displayed in the #buttonShiny div but it doesn't work

The script tag to call the JS file is right before the closing body tag

Comment: Where does `displayButtonShiny ()` get called? Please provide a [mre] that demonstrtes the issue and expand on what "doesn't work" means in more specific detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you declare the function but never use it. Add only `displayButtonShiny("x")` to your js code.

```js
const shiny = document.getElementById('buttonShiny');

const displayButtonShiny = (pokemon) => {
  const shinyHTMLString = `
    <button class="buttons_shiny" onclick="document.getElementById('pokemonSprite').src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/${pokemon.id}.png'">Shiny</button>
    <button class="buttons_normal" onclick="document.getElementById('pokemonSprite').src='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/${pokemon.id}.png'">Normal</button>
    `;
    shiny.innerHTML = shinyHTMLString;
};

displayButtonShiny("x"); // x = your pokemon
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
   <div class="buttons_inner" id="buttonShiny">btn1</div>
</div>
```